# Select all elements whose name starts with a specific string in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I would like to select all the html elements that start with "my-element".

For example:

```
my-element-1 {

    background-color: red;
    ...
}
my-element-2 {
    background-color: red;
    ...
}
my-element-3 {
    background-color: red;
    ...
}
```

would be something like:

```
[tag*="my-element"] {
    background-color: red;
    ...
}
```

That syntax works when selecting classes like this:

```
div[class^='myclass'], div[class*=' myclass']{
    color: #F00;
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: I think most people would just add a common class to all of the relevant elements and use that as the selector.

Comment: Thirtydot pretty much hit the nail on the head, add a dormant class that you want to over ride it with using the !important clause

Comment: @DataCure There is no need for `!important` as it removes the target element from the cascade. And you don't need to use class-names, any attributes will do.

Comment: Im wondering what html tags you have in mind.

Comment: now the real question: what are those elements that start like this? and why you have such structure? ... I think we should do things in a good way instead of trying to find complex solution

Comment: @TemaniAfif Not by tag name, only by attributes. OP seems to want to select by custom tag name using the attr selector powers... which is not possible.

Comment: @JoãoPedroSáMedeiros Do you only want to do this in CSS? Or would you be open to JavaScript?

Comment: I'm using Angular, so I can create my own components. Thanks.

Comment: @TylerH It needs to be only CSS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, there is no CSS selector like "wildcard elements" to retrieve elements based on a partial element name.

You can:

**A)** Use class-names or any other attributes, since element attributes can be accessed using selectors with regular expressions. (As in your question.)

```
my-element[my-attribute] { … }
```

**B)** Use a CSS pre-processor like SCSS to generate a list of such element names:

```
@for $i from 1 through 3 {
  my-element-#{$i} {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

**C)** Or just write them one after another in the CSS, delimited by a comma: (This is the same as writing each rule independently as in your question.)

```
my-element-1,
my-element-2,
my-element-3 {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: @JoãoPedroSáMedeiros All this for only 3 elements at the end! :p

Comment: @TemaniAfif At least now we have an answer for this question on stackoverflow =D

Comment: @JoãoPedroSáMedeiros we already have plenty of answers for this on SO ;)

Comment: Same answer for a different question

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create your own html tags it is not HTML5 format. Dont really know how this "elements" part suppose to work in your code, but you can use:

> div[id^="my-element"]{//code}

It is a selector that picks elements by the same beginning part. Cite from:
[W3C](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/)

> E[foo^="bar"] an E element whose "foo" attribute value begins exactly with the string "bar"

For example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div[id^="my-element"]{
//code}</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="my-element-1">Content</div>
<div id="my-element-2">Content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I would recommend adding an explanation of what your CSS selector does to improve this answer.

Comment: I'm using angular to create components

Comment: @TylerH Done, hope it's better now.

Comment: @JoãoPedroSáMedeiros Never used angular so i have no idea how these selectors works along. There was no angular tag so I assumed it's clean html&css. My bad.